# el jarrón vs la urna

Tags: vocabulario

Is "el jarrón" ever used to describe an urn in the sense of holding the ashes of the dead after cremation? Or is that meaning used more with "la urna"?

The RAE definition for el jarrón doesn't seem to mention cremation:

1. m. Pieza arquitectónica en forma de jarro, con que se decoran edificios, galerías, escaleras, jardines, etc., puesta casi siempre sobre un pedestal y como adorno de remate.
2. m. Vaso, por lo general de porcelana, artísticamente labrado, para adornar consolas, chimeneas, etc.

Sin.:
florero, búcaro, vaso.

Whereas the RAE definition of la urna does mention this in #3:

1. f. Caja para depositar las papeletas o números en los sorteos y en las votaciones secretas.
2. f. Caja de cristales planos a propósito para tener dentro visibles y resguardados del polvo efigies u otros objetos preciosos.
3. f. Caja de metal, piedra u otra materia, que sirve para varios usos, como guardar dinero, los restos o las cenizas de los cadáveres humanos, etc.

Sin.:
arca, arqueta, receptáculo, caja, envase.
4. f. Medida antigua para líquidos.

5. f. Ven. ataúd.

Sin.:
ataúd, caja, cajón.

Comment: Según mi experiencia, siempre escuché *urna* para el lugar donde se guardan las cenizas. *Jarrón* es un término muy genérico, pero no me parece apropiado para tal contexto.

Comment: urn versus vase, a large vase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo estuve pensando, y me decanto por decir que **no**. La razón es sencilla: en el español, para denominar objetos, a menudo importa mucho **la función** que cumple dicho objeto dentro del plexo en el que se encuentra, tanto o más que las características físicas que el mismo pueda tener. Por lo tanto, el objeto no cobra sentido sino *después* de haberlo considerado como parte de un todo. Cada ámbito requiere comprenderlo como un todo y las funciones que cada objeto cumple, para así poder asignarle a cada objeto su respectivo término. Es lo que tanto le llaman **hablar con propiedad**.

En tu caso estamos hablando de un contexto de un cementerio o un velorio; es una especie de ‘recipiente’ pero *no es cualquiera*: es uno que contiene los restos de lo que otrora fuera una persona, lo cual es bien distinto de un recipiente que por ejemplo guarda basura. Por lo tanto, alguien que le diga ‘tarro’, ‘jarra’, ‘jarrón’, ‘vaso’, ‘vasija’‚ ‘tacho’, ‘tambo’, etc. en mi opinión sería un desubicado. ‘Recipiente’ parecería una suerte de intento por salir del paso usando vocabulario genérico, pero tampoco termina de cerrar.

En conclusión, hay ciertos términos especializados que hacen referencia a la función que el objeto debe cumplir, más que a la forma que éste pudiera llegar a tener. *Urna* es uno de dichos términos y conozco dos acepciones según dos respectivas posibles funciones: o bien contener los sobres con los votos en un sufragio, o bien contener las cenizas de una persona muerta cremada.

Para reforzar el argumento, algunos otros ejemplos:

- En náutica, estando en una embarcación, no le digas ‘sogas’ a los *cabos* a menos que quieras hacer enojar al capitán. Tampco digas ‘enrollar’ en lugar de *adujar* un cabo—te van a echar!
- En electrónica, no le digas ‘perillas’ a los *potenciómetros*, sería una gran equivocación porque una perilla no necesariamente consiste en un potenciómetro. Tampoco confundas *potenciómetro* con *preset*.
- En cocina, no confundas *olla* con *cacerola*; las dimensiones y los platos que se cocinen dentro pueden ser diferentes aunque todo el mundo confunde ambas cosas.
- En el ajedrez, no le digas *reina* a la *dama*. Nah mentira, ambos términos son perfectamente válidos. Sin embargo, es mucho más práctico decirle *dama* y es lo que casi todo el mundo hace porque ayuda a la hora de anotar jugadas (D=dama, R=rey).
- Por último, no caigas en el vicio que tienen muchos nativos de llamarle ‘coso’ o ‘cosito’ a cada objeto que tienen, usan y se van hallando por la simple fiaca de no haber estudiado el vocabulario adecuado que se requiere para nombrar adecuadamente a cada cosa. Vas a dar una pésima impresión de persona inculta a tus pares.

Saludos y Felices Fiestas